# fomat partial text of Text widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

My Text widget looks like `Text("Last Active: some location area..")`.

I can change text style of complete text using style. but I just like to change Last active as a bold. `Text("<b>Last Active</b> some location area name..")`

If I go with Row for separate text it will work but render a problem of spacing.

What's the best solution for this. And to make it bold is the only requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

RichText is solution

```
RichText(text: TextSpan(children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'Last Active', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' some location area name..')
    ]))
```

Comment: Text comes blank (no text visible) - does not work

Comment: @Elmar seems like problem not with solution https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html Maybe you could try to find your exactly problem before downvoting

Comment: The problem is that style should be defined at least like this style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style). Otherwise, text is the same color as the background and not visible. Not defining any style causes issue.

Answer (score 13):

I had problems with [Andrey Turkovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7130820/andrey-turkovsky) solution, the text area would be blank. I did find a slightly alternative solution. (I did want to comment to Andreys, and maybe he might be able to explain the differences between the two, Id be interested)

```
  Text.rich(
    TextSpan(
      children: [
        TextSpan(
            text: 'Last Active',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        TextSpan(text: ' some location area name..')
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. @Andrey Turkovsky's solution shows up as blank over here. But this solution worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

Working solution in 2022:

```
RichText( text: TextSpan(text: 'Last Active: ', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black), children:          
<TextSpan>[
TextSpan(text: 'some location area...', style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style), 
], ), ),
```